# Field generated by a class of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a little confused by the concept of "set" and "set of set". In particular, given $\Omega$={1,2,3,4,5,6} , and C={{2,4},{6}}. What is the Field generated by C?

My answer would be $\sigma$(C)={$\Omega$, $\emptyset$, C, {1,3,5}, {2,4,6},{1,3,5,{2,4},{6}}. Is that correct? Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Field generated by C"?

Comment: @ZxJx Dunno, but I'm pretty sure OP's use of field isn't the canonical one.

Comment: @AkaiM I think you have a typo after the 5th comma.  Perhaps instead of  

{1,3,5,{2,4}  

you just need to have {2,4}.

Now this looks like you have a subset of the power set of $\Omega$ generated by taking unions, intersections, and complements.  Usually we call this a $\sigma$-algebra, but according to Wikipedia these are also called $\sigma$-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) should consist of subsets of $\Omega$, contain all elements of $C$ (i.e., contain $\{2,4\}$ an $\{6\}$ and be closed under intersection, union, complement.
So far we have
$$\tag1\{2,4\}\in \sigma(C) $$
$$\tag2\{6\}\in \sigma(C) $$
because these are the generators,
$$\tag3\emptyset\in \sigma(C) $$
because this holds for any field, or by taking the intersection $\{2,4\}\cap \{6\}$
$$\tag 4\Omega\in \sigma(C)$$
again because this is always the case or as complement of $\emptyset$.
$$\tag5 \{1,3,5,6\}\in\sigma(C)$$
as complement of $\{2,4\}$,
$$\tag5 \{1,2,3,4, 5\}\in\sigma(C)$$
as complement of $\{6\}$,
$$\tag7\{2,4,6\}\in\sigma(C)$$
as union of the two generators
$$\tag8\{1,3,5\}\in\sigma(C)$$
as complement of the latter.
All further unions, intersections, complements are already listed above.

Comment: So the whole set C={{2,4},{6}} is not in the field?

Comment: @AkaiM No, the field consists of subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $C$ is not such a subset: it has as elements two such subsets $\{2,4\}$ and $\{6\}$ that *are* in the field, as they must be. $C \subset \sigma(C)$, not $C \in \sigma(C)$ ("type error").